# Externalize different environment variables for different environments in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, docker, webpack

**Is there any way to externalize completely environment variables (secret keys included) in a React app in a DevOps context?**
We want to automate our builds for different environments (each environment has its own environment variables).
We have looked into environment variables in React using Webpack, but it doesn't quite satisfy our need and we can't externalize environment variables with this approach. Besides, we would have to explicitly declare all these variables inside webpack config file, which would be bloated if we did this.
We think that the best way to go is to put api secrets in Firebase and runtime specifics inside a jenkins script.

We are using Jenkins as our CI/CD server and the app runs is deployed with nginx in a Docker container.

Comment: Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64807289/how-to-handle-multiple-environments-in-react-app/69292596#69292596

Answer (score 1):

You may create two .env files, .env and .env.prod at the root level and can define your particular 'variables' related to specific environment into these env files. Then in your code you should be able to access them through `process.env.NODE_ENV`

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
    //Execute this in production environment
    var url= `${process.env.REACT_APP_AC_ORIGIN}/`;
    url = url + ...,
}else{
    //Execute this in dev environment
    var url= `${process.env.REACT_APP_AC_ORIGIN}/`;
    url = url + ...,
}
```

.env

```
REACT_APP_AC_ORIGIN=https://example1.com
```

.env.prod

```
REACT_APP_AC_ORIGIN=https://example2.com
```

If you have multiple environments, say, production, staging, QA, and so on, you may even consider generating dynamic URLS assuming that different environments will be accessed by different hostnames in the browser, Something like this:

**api-config.js**

```
  let backendHost;
const apiVersion = 'v1';

const hostname = window && window.location && window.location.hostname;

if(hostname === 'realsite.com') {
  backendHost = 'https://api.realsite.com';
} else if(hostname === 'staging.realsite.com') {
  backendHost = 'https://staging.api.realsite.com';
} else if(/^qa/.test(hostname)) {
  backendHost = `https://api.${hostname}`;
} else {
  backendHost = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_HOST || 'http://localhost:8080';
}

export const API_ROOT = `${backendHost}/api/${apiVersion}`;
```

And then you can import it like this:

```
import { API_ROOT } from './api-config';

function getUsers() {
  return fetch(`${API_ROOT}/users`)
    .then(res => res.json)
    .then(json => json.data.users);
}
```

OR, you can define your variables at run time on different environments.

```
$ REACT_APP_API_HOST=example.com yarn run build

# The resulting app would have
#   process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST === "example.com"
#   process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
```

Ref : https://daveceddia.com/multiple-environments-with-react/

Comment: We have 4 environments in total. Is it possible to add other .env files with different suffixes? Will webpack pick them up?

Comment: I think in that case you might consider configuring your  API Endpoints Dynamically. See this: https://daveceddia.com/multiple-environments-with-react/

Comment: @ABGR Will this approach applies to reducing the number of builds required for each environment?  I mean, I don't want to create a different build for each environment, just one time for all of them.