# How to handle multiple environments in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a small project including react frontend and Java backend with two environments.

I struggle on the idea how to work with multiple environemnts, I declare API url using axios:

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://api.dev.project.local/api/v1`,
});
```

But this works only for one environment, how to change API url after the package is built? I don't think it is a good practise to create two builds (one for dev and one for prod), because it could create mess inside artifacts manager (we use Azure Artifacs Feed).

How do you solve this problem?

Comment: try using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)

Comment: @JosephD. but using webpack will produce the same result, right? multiple packages, each for different environment?

Comment: @FilipNiko, right. different webpack config for each environment: dev, prod and common. Using [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge) to generate different output bundles.  Not familiar with Azure but maybe the bundle hashes can be handy.

Comment: @JosephD. Thanks for the output, but how to handle versions in registry (artifact feed), if one can have different API configuration than other so I am unable to deploy every pacakge to every environment...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In case you are with **create-react-app**, and only need local and production environment go with [Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) build-in feature. Otherwise, a useful alternative is **env-cmd**.

Install env-cmd, as a development dependency:

```
npm i -D env-cmd
```

Add **.env** file (at project root, same for all environments):

```
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT = https://default.example.com
```

Add **.env.qa** file:

```
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT = https://qa.example.com
```

Add **.env.staging** file:

```
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT = https://stage.example.com
```

Add **.env.production** file:

```
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT = https://production.example.com
```

Update package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:qa": "env-cmd -f .env.qa npm run-script build",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging npm run-script build",
  }
}
```

Note that default **start** and **build** create-react-app commands are using **.env** and **.env.production** respectively, and have no need of **env-cmd**.

Ready to use in our code

```
const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL;
```

*And, we also can use env-cmd for start command at development environment.*

Comment: This works thanks! Could you explain why we have to use `npm run-script build` in the custom environment while default build command uses `react-scripts build`?

Comment: @RaphaelPinel `npm run-script build` is invoking your default build command. That way if you need to change the build command, you only need to change it in one place, rather than for all environments.

Comment: I like this solution, but how does it work with `cross-env`? For example: `"build:qa": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=QA HTTPS=true BUILD_PATH=../wwwroot react-scripts build"`

Answer (score 2):

i think you should use environment variables and create an .env file and its seprate from your project.

for more information you can [react docs about environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

or you can use [npm scripts variables](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts/#environment)

I hope it was useful.

Comment: Thanks, this is kinda approach we are trying to implement now, however I am not sure how this will solve issues with multiple build results?

Comment: with having diffrent .env files,or in second solution with having diffrent script for builing in development and production

Comment: Understood, but this is something I would like to kinda avoid, I would like to have one build for all environments, I dont trust build idempotence much...