# How to set up multiple environments in React

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I have a react application (built with create react app) that has to be deployed to two different environments. One is `mother`, the other one is `father`, and each environment has `prod`, `uat` and `dev`. I added the following files:

```
.env.mother.prod
.env.mother.uat
.env.mother.dev
.env.father.prod
.env.father.uat
.env.father.dev
```

How can I set the script so that I can run something like this `npm build --person mother --env prod`? Is it possible to make a build with flags and I pass the environments over there?

Something like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start [person] [env]",
  "build": "react-scripts build [person] [env]"
},
```

Comment: You may try the following:
https://www.codingdeft.com/posts/react-environment-variables/

Comment: I'd advise you to create a custom webpack config, this way you can easily pass variables to your bundler from package.json. CRA is quite limited.

Comment: Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64807289/how-to-handle-multiple-environments-in-react-app/69292596#69292596